# Unable to load a class from the lib folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to load my class **fine.rb** from **lib/info_test**, but it do not work. I changed the following class **config/application.rb** as follows:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/info_test)
```

If I save my class directly in the folder **lib** it works, but not in **lib/info_test**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work and it does work for me. Check the value of

```
<application_name>::Application.config.autoload_paths
```

in `rails c`

**UPDATE**

Then try

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/info_test)
```

in application.rb.